# Why does Object.assign add to the prototype's constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, object-composition

I am learning composition in Javascript and was wondering why Object.assign() in my code is adding methods to the prototype's constructor rather than the object's constructor. I will link the code below. Basically, the code is adding two methods (eat and walk) to the Person object by using Object.assign(). But, as the image below shows, the console is displaying the methods as belonging to the Person.prototype's constructor rather than the Person object itself. I must be overthinking it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

---

[image]

---

Code

```js
const canEat = {
    eat() {
        this.hunger--;
        console.log('eating');
    }
};

const canWalk = {
    walk: function() {
        console.log('walking');
    }
};

const canSwim = {
    swim: function() {
        console.log("swim");
    }
};

function Person() {

}

Object.assign(Person,canEat,canWalk);
const person = new Person();
console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `Object.assign` is evaluated:

```
Object.assign(Person, canEat, canWalk);
```

`eat` and `walk` properties are assigned to `Person` function.

When the instance of `Person` is created:

```
const person = new Person();
```

Then we have a new object which has a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property pointed to the `Person` function. However the new object has neither `eat` nor `walk` properties (those belong to `Person` [constructor] function).

If you want to make `eat` and `walk` properties available for instances of `Person`, you should assign those methods to `Person.prototype` instead:

```
Object.assign(Person.prototype, canEat, canWalk);
```

Because when an object is created with [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description) operator, it inherits not from the constructor function `Person`, but from constructor function prototype `Person.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not examining the `Person` object. It kind of looks like you are if you're not familiar with the `console.log` output, because the first line says `Person`, but you're logging an instance of `Person`, not `Person` itself.

The prototype of the instance you're logging is `Person.prototype`, and the `Person.prototype` object has a `constructor` property referring to the `Person` function. When you see `eat` and `walk` listed as properties under `constructor`, that means they're properties of the `Person` function, as they should be.